# Where do I find a delete button to delete files from my Dropbox folder?

Tags: dropbox

Where is the delete button to delete files from my Dropbox folder?

I would like to delete all of my photos, and I tried following directions for deleting files, but I never saw a "Delete" button.

Answer (score 1):

Select the files you want to delete first:

[image]